# Must issue a STARTTLS command first when sending email from jenkins on Windows

Tags: java, jenkins, smtp

I have jenkins installed on my windows desktop and having issues configuring it to send emails from my outlook account as it uses TLS instead of SSL. I have done some research and some forums suggested adding the JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS to the jenkins.xml file and doing a restart however this didn't work for me.

JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS      -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

My SMTP settings are 
SERVER smtp-mail.outlook.com
SMTP PORT 587
Use SSL unchecked
Username *****
Password ******

Error is below 
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

```
  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057)

  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1580)

  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1097)

  at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)

  at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)

  at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.doSendTestMail(Mailer.java:581)

  at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source)

  at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)

  at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)
```

Comment: So what about checking the _Use SSL_ option?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure jenkins configuration file to enable TLS. For ubuntu it is in the path `/etc/default/jenkins`. 
Use following statement to do so.

```
JAVA_ARGS = "-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true"
```

it worked for me. good luck.